# How can I hide/show the Ubuntu dock with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

I am not able to hide/unhide the Launcher/Dash/Dock from the keyboard in Ubuntu 17.10 or in Ubuntu 18.04. Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not exactly what it's intended for, but you can use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to show the Ubuntu dock when it's hidden.

The actual use of the key combination is somewhat different, the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> combination shows the dock with numbers next to each icon in the dock. Then you release <kbd>q</kbd> and press the number to launch or switch to the associated application.

If this feature is disabled, run the following to enable it first:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to hide/unhide on the go, the following extension does it.
It has a button in the top bar.
See the Gnome extension [Dock Hide Button by sanjarcode](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3085/dock-hide-button/).