# Mouse snagging on autohidden vertical dock between monitors

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock

So I was always a big fan of Ubuntu GNOME, and so was very stoked to see GNOME become the default interface manager for Ubuntu.

One of the things that has bugged me, and I seem to be unable to find the answer to, is that in prior versions of Ubuntu GNOME (before 18) the dock was always hidden by default, and one had to explicitly push the <kbd>super</kbd> key to show the hidden dock and access it's functionality.

Since Ubuntu 18 the dock is visible by default. Okay, so I activated the auto-hide setting. Although, the problem being that the functionality is different to before.

To be specific, when you have a multiple monitor setup, and the dock is on the middle or right monitor, with a monitor to the left, when you transition the mouse between the monitors, then the dock attempts to catch your mouse while it becomes visible.

This can be incredibly annoying because it grabs and removes mouse control (briefly) every time you cross over from the boundary of one monitor to another (with the dock in between).

There is an inability to control the settings specifically.

Some sort of setting to hide the dock, and do nothing on mouse over. Only show when the <kbd>super</kbd> key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer is to install the "Dash to Dock" plugin through the Software Center.

Then after "Dash to Dock" is installed and launched it is possible to access the plugin settings from right clicking on the applications icon on the new (identical looking) dock.

On the "Position and size" tab, enable "Intelligent autohide", and then open the Intelligent autohide customization window. Make sure the "Push to show: require pressure to show the dock" is disabled. (This disables the snagging)

Then I also enabled the "Dodge windows" settings, so that the dock shows on empty workspaces, and further replicates the original Ubuntu Gnome functionality.

Regards,

Note that it doesn't seem possible to just disable the default Dock from the "Tweaks" tool. Although after you have applied your new Dock settings through the "Dash to Dock" extension, you can disable it, and the new settings seem to apply just fine to the Original Dock.

Comment: Although it looks the original dock is still actually rendering underneath the new "Dash to Dock" that is visible. Not sure how to hide the original dock.

Comment: Running Dash to Dock along with the default Ubuntu Dock is [not a good idea](https://askubuntu.com/q/975387/480481).

Comment: Thanks, found and disabled the Default Dock extension under tweak tools. Will make an edit to the answer.

Comment: Seems like disabling the default Ubuntu Dock under with the "Tweaks" tool doesn't have any effect, although disabling the "Dask to Dock" with the "Tweaks" tool actually leaves the "Dash to Dock" settings applied to the default Ubuntu Dock, which is good enough for me.

Comment: Yes, because the default Ubuntu Dock is a pre-installed system extension: https://askubuntu.com/q/1030138/480481

Answer (score 9):

Since Ubuntu's dock is a fork of "Dash to Dock", it has the same configuration options. Editing them is just slightly more convoluted:

1. Open a terminal
2. Run this to **disable** `require-pressure-to-show`:

   ```bsh
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock require-pressure-to-show false
   ```
3. Run this to **enable** `intellihide`:

   ```bsh
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide true
   ```
4. Enjoy finally having a usable multi-monitor setup!

Comment: Note that even with `animation-time` set to 0, you may still need to make your cursor linger at low (very) speeds near the border between monitors before the dock will appear; it stays hidden when passing over it quickly. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to edit this speed-cutoff, which is annoying for sensitive mice. As stated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012706/how-to-hide-show-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10-18-04-with-keyboard-shortcut) you can use **ctrl-Q** to force it to show if it's being stubborn, without messing with the position of your other windows.