# How can I bind a key to show/hide the dock on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-dock, autohide

I like the idea of being able to hide the dock and use as much screen space as possible, but I get really anoyed with the default bahaviour of the "Auto-hide dock" option. Sometimes I hover the pointer over the dock space, and it just won't show up, so I have to keep repeating this action until it slides in.

I'd like to bind a key to hide or show the dock (something like a switch key) instead of having to hover the cursor over it to do so. Can someone help me?

PS: If I could use a mouse macro to do so would be even better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide/show the Ubuntu dock with a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012706/how-can-i-hide-show-the-ubuntu-dock-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Not sure how to configure a custom key but a single press/release of the `Super` key should achieve what you want (the `Windows` key by default on most "Windows" keyboards).

Comment: @pomsky sort of. I want the dock to behave somewhat like that, but with a specific keybind to show/hide it. The `super` + `q` combination slides the dock in, but I don't want those numbers on it (that "select and lauch" feature). Also, when I press `super` + `q`, the dock closes after some seconds. I want something more like a "switch" key bind.

Comment: That's the best you can get for now afaik.